# HTML5 Canvas — Line too thick

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

These past two days I've been playing around with the HTML5 canvas element.  I'm attempting to draw a maze, but I'm at a stand-still.  The line I drew isn't consistent with the `lineWidth` property.  It's ~2px thicker.

I'm familiar with the half pixel problem with the canvas element, and you need to start at `0.5`, but I don't know where I need to put the `0.5` in my code.

If I'm not mistaken, if you want to make the vertical line consistent, the x argument needs to be .5 and for horizontal line, y value needs to be .5?

[image]

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c"),
    c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    hallwayWidth = w * 0.10; /*18px*/

c.beginPath();
c.lineWidth = 4;
c.moveTo(0, 0);
c.lineTo(w / 3, 0);
c.moveTo(0, 0);
c.lineTo(0, h);
c.moveTo(w, 0);
c.lineTo(w, h);
c.moveTo(w / 3 + hallwayWidth, 0);
c.lineTo(w, 0);
c.moveTo(0, h);
c.lineTo(w / 2, h);
c.moveTo(w / 2 + hallwayWidth, h);
c.lineTo(w, h);

/*code for thick line*/
c.moveTo(hallwayWidth, 0);
c.lineTo(hallwayWidth, w / 3);

c.stroke();
```

[Here's the link to the code](http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/7fyL7a1o/3/)

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#pixel-madness

Comment: @Dave I know, I was looking at that but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Right here: `c.moveTo(hallwayWidth+c.lineWidth/2, 0);` and here `c.lineTo(hallwayWidth+c.lineWidth/2, w / 3);` The point that you moveTo or lineTo is one that is in the middle of the line's thickness.

Comment: Since you're using an even-valued line width, the 0.5 offset isn't relevant to your problem, but you still need to know *why* the issue occurs, otherwise you won't understand why `x=w*0.1` can cause "fuzzy" lines. If you're wondering about your outside lines, it's simply because 2 pixels of the line is inside the canvas, and 2 pixels is outside. You can only see the half which is inside. Just nudge all your lines away from the edges by 2 pixels or more.

Comment: @Dave Ohhhh, that makes sense.  I thought the thicker line was the problem.  So, the outside lines *aren't* 4px thick, the inside one is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use 0.5 , when the lineWidth is 4 you must use:

- `2` instead of `0`
- `(w-2)` instead of `w`
- `(h-2)` instead of `h`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c"),
     c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
     w = canvas.width,
     h = canvas.height,
     hallwayWidth = w * 0.10, /*18px*/
        l = 2;

 c.beginPath();
 c.lineWidth = l*2;
 c.moveTo(l,l);
 c.lineTo(w / 3, l);
 c.moveTo(l, l);
 c.lineTo(l, h-l);
 c.moveTo(w-l, l);
 c.lineTo(w-l, h-l);
 c.moveTo(w / 3 + hallwayWidth, l);
 c.lineTo(w-l, l);
 c.moveTo(l, h-l);
 c.lineTo(w / 2, h-l);
 c.moveTo(w / 2 + hallwayWidth, h-l);
 c.lineTo(w-l, h-l);

    /*code for thick line*/
    
 c.moveTo(hallwayWidth, l);
    c.lineTo(hallwayWidth, w / 3);

 c.stroke();
```

```css
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    /* border: 1px solid red; */
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Another option(to avoid the "lost pixels" in the corners):draw 2 different paths and use for the "border" a lineWidth of 8

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c"),
  c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  w = canvas.width,
  h = canvas.height,
  hallwayWidth = w * 0.10; /*18px*/

c.beginPath();
c.lineWidth = 8;
c.moveTo(0, 0);
c.lineTo(w / 3, 0);
c.moveTo(0, 0);
c.lineTo(0, h);
c.moveTo(w, 0);
c.lineTo(w, h);
c.moveTo(w / 3 + hallwayWidth, 0);
c.lineTo(w, 0);
c.moveTo(0, h);
c.lineTo(w / 2, h);
c.moveTo(w / 2 + hallwayWidth, h);
c.lineTo(w, h);
c.stroke();
/*code for thick line*/
c.beginPath();
c.lineWidth = 4;
c.moveTo(hallwayWidth, 0);
c.lineTo(hallwayWidth, w / 3);
c.stroke();
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: I guess it should not be `w - 2` or `h - 2` but `w` and `h` because you lost 1 pixel on each corner

Comment: @Hacketo: With `w` and `h`  the bottom and right side would only be 2px width, I've added another suggestion to avoid these "lost pixels"